# Most efficient way to replace large redis keys

Tags: redis, sortedset

I have a large Redis sorted set. We need to re-index the data in the set daily, while clients actively request data from the set. My plan is to simply build a second set using a different key and then replace the existing key with the new one:

1. Build new "indexed" sorted set
2. RENAME "indexed" set to "live" to replace existing "live" set.

Looking at the [RENAME](http://redis.io/commands/rename) documentation, it states:

> If newkey already exists it is overwritten, when this happens RENAME executes an implicit DEL operation, so if the deleted key contains a very big value it may cause high latency even if RENAME itself is usually a constant-time operation.

I'm wondering, then, if it's better to rename the "live" sorted set (e.g. to "dead"), then rename the new "indexed" sorted set to "live" -- and pipeline those requests. And only then, issue a separate DEL command to delete the "dead" set:

1. Build new "indexed" sorted set
2. pipeline: RENAME existing "live" set to "dead"
3. pipeline: RENAME new "indexed" set to "live"
4. DEL "dead" set

ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `DEL`, you are only postponing the problem. During the `DEL`, redis blocks other clients.

First, I'd investigate how big the problem is. It **can** be a problem, for example deleting a 3.5GB `ZSET` key takes about 2 seconds on our staging system.

If it's a problem, split up the `DEL` by using [`ZREMRANGEBYRANK`](http://redis.io/commands/zremrangebyrank) and `ZCARD`.

Pipelining is efficient (non-transactional ofcourse), so it helps to determine the total size upfront by `ZCARD`, and after that, issue N `ZREMRANGEBYRANK` commands (piped) with a range of (example) `-10000 0`, ending with '0 -1'. As soon as all members are deleted, Redis automatically deletes the key (the Sorted Set) itself.

Hope this helps, TW

Comment: Good point. Background key expiration isn't blocking, is it? What if we set a 1 second EXPIRE on it?

Comment: I expect expire to __block__. Not 100% sure, someone please correct me if I'm wrong. Expire lives on the key, not the members. In the AOF as well as slave synchoronisation, technically a DEL is what will happen. See [here](http://redis.io/commands/expire).